# Is there a way to use VBA to select certain columns from a text file and create a new text with just those columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a text file which has >255 columns, when I only need the first 200 columns, is there a way I can use VBA in excel to read in the original text file, take the first 200 columns, and then use this to create a new text file?
I could then read in this new file into access and filter the way I need too.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You can record a macro while performing those steps.  That will get youm ost of the way there.

Comment: Power query is a good tool for data manipulation.

Comment: You could write an import function directly in Access that would write the TXT file to a RecordSet and then use that to create an Insert statement to import the data. Your Insert statement would only include the first 200 columns form the RecordSet..  It's fast and avoids the middle man of Excel.  With 200 columns it's just a really long bit of SQL.

Comment: If your column names in your TXT file are the same as the columns names in Access, you can iterate through them to build you SQL statement.  That would save you a LOT of typing.

Comment: Hi Frank, this sounds like the kind of method I am looking for, I would prefer not to use excel, I am struggling to find anything that shows me how write an import function directly in access that would write the TXT file to a recordset, do you know where I could look to know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in text import only supports a maximum of 255 fields so that is not an option. You don't say whether the text file is delimited or whether the fields are fixed length. In either case you can read the text file using `ReadLine` with the [TextStream object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/textstream-object). If the records are delimited then you can use the `Split` function to load the fields into an array and process from there. If it is fixed length, use the `Mid` function to parse the record.

If you don't want to use a `TextStream` object then you can also link the file in MS Access as a *fixed width* file with a length equal to the longest record. When the `Link Text` wizard opens, select `Fixed Width` and click the `Advanced` button. This will allow you to set the length of the single field. Keep clicking next until you get to the `Field Options` screen. If your record length is greater than 255 then you should change the `Data Type` to `Memo`. You can then read this as you would any MS Access table and get the columns using the options I mentioned earlier.